# How would I go about disabling a UIButton if the UIScrollView has scrolled more than a certain amount?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

How would I go about disabling a UIButton if the UIScrollView has scrolled more than a certain amount?

this is what I've been trying. Perhaps it's the wrong scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (_scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 100)       {

        mapLaunchButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Did you make this class the scroll view's delegate?

Comment: I have this <UIScrollViewDelegate> in the interface

Comment: You also have to set the scroll view's `delegate` property to `self` (or whatever object you want to use). If you are using IB you need to connect stuff together (I don't use IB).

Comment: @0x7fffffff when the scroll view has been scrolled 100pts from it's position that was set in viewDidload. thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy I did that too. programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Simple! You'll need to create a variable to store the starting position of the scroll view though. It should be a CGPoint. Set it to the scroll view's content offset in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` (where the scroll view starts moving) and then do comparison in scrollViewDidScroll similarly to how you were doing it before.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    startingPoint = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= startingPoint.y + 100.0f) {
        mapLaunchButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you *may* need to modify the values I've provided slightly depending on the starting position of the scroll view, and the direction in which you'd like to monitor the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (_scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 100)       {

      mapLaunchButton.enabled = NO;
    }

    else  {

      mapLaunchButton.enabled = YES;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is OK, but you have to **add the delegate** for the scrollView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // do whatever
    ...

    // Add the delegate for the scrollview
    [_scrollView setDelegate:self];
}
```